# Can't perform a segue after signup using PFSignUpViewControllerDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm using `PFSignUpViewControllerDelegate` and I want to perform a segue after user signup to setup their profile... But nothing works! Where should I put this code?

`self.performSegueWithIdentifier("setupCliente", sender: self)`

**My Code:**

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import ParseUI
import Bolts
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
import FBSDKShareKit
import CoreLocation

struct localizacaoActualizada {

static var rua = ""
static var localidade = ""
static var codigopostal = ""
static var giropostal = ""
static var country = ""


}


class ViewController: UIViewController, ENSideMenuDelegate, PFLogInViewControllerDelegate, PFSignUpViewControllerDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {



var logInViewController: PFLogInViewController! = PFLogInViewController()
var signUpViewController: PFSignUpViewController! = PFSignUpViewController()

var localidadeActual = ""

@IBOutlet weak var userLogedIn: UILabel!

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.sideMenuController()?.sideMenu?.delegate = self

    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()



    // Se ta loggado
    var user = PFUser.currentUser()

    if (user?.username != nil) {



      //  self.performSegueWithIdentifier("aposLogin", sender: self)


    }



}


override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)

    var user = PFUser.currentUser()
    self.userLogedIn.text = user?.username




     if (user?.username == nil) {

        self.logInViewController.fields = ( PFLogInFields.UsernameAndPassword | PFLogInFields.LogInButton | PFLogInFields.SignUpButton | PFLogInFields.PasswordForgotten | PFLogInFields.DismissButton )

        //PFLogInFields.Facebook




        var logInLogoTitle = UILabel()
        logInLogoTitle.text = "ParaFora"

        var SignUpLogoTitle = UILabel()
        SignUpLogoTitle.text = "ParaFora"

        //self.logInViewController.facebookPermissions = [ "friends_about_me" ]
        self.logInViewController.logInView!.logo = logInLogoTitle
        self.logInViewController.delegate = self
        self.signUpViewController.signUpView!.logo = SignUpLogoTitle
        self.signUpViewController.delegate = self
        self.logInViewController.signUpController = self.signUpViewController

    }

     else {

        //Tentativa 1
        //self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        var user = PFUser.currentUser()
        user?["localidade"] = localidadeActual
        user?.saveInBackground()



        //tentativa 2

        //var user = PFUser.currentUser()
        //var idUser = user?["objectId"] as! String
       // println("O id do utilizador actual:" + idUser)

       // var query = PFQuery(className:"User")
       // query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(idUser) {
       //     (User: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
       //     if error != nil {
       //         println(error)
       //     } else if let User = User {
      //          println("Tentativa de escrever" + self.localidadeActual + "no servidor")
      //          User["localidade"] = self.localidadeActual
      //          User.saveInBackground()
     //           println("done?")
     //       }
       // }
        //



   // self.performSegueWithIdentifier("aposLogin", sender: self)
    }
}

//Localizacao

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!)
{

    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error)->Void in

        if (error != nil)
        {
            println("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        if placemarks.count > 0
        {
            let pm = placemarks[0] as! CLPlacemark
            self.displayLocationInfo(pm)
        }
        else
        {
            println("Error with the data.")
        }
    })
}


func displayLocationInfo(placemark: CLPlacemark)
{
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    //self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    println(placemark.locality)
    println(placemark.postalCode)
    println(placemark.administrativeArea)
    println(placemark.country)
    println(placemark.location)
    println(placemark.administrativeArea)
    println(placemark.subAdministrativeArea)

//        println(placemark.addressDictionary)
  //      println(placemark.areasOfInterest)

    localidadeActual = placemark.locality
    localizacaoActualizada.rua = placemark.name
    localizacaoActualizada.localidade = placemark.locality

    //Guarda o codigo postal na estrutura
    if count(placemark.postalCode) > 4{
    localizacaoActualizada.codigopostal = placemark.postalCode.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(start: advance(placemark.postalCode.startIndex, 0), end: advance(placemark.postalCode.endIndex, -3)))
    localizacaoActualizada.giropostal = placemark.postalCode.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(start: advance(placemark.postalCode.startIndex, 4), end: advance(placemark.postalCode.endIndex, 0)))

    }

    else {
        localizacaoActualizada.codigopostal = placemark.postalCode
    }





    // Obtem a localidade no serv


    var user = PFUser.currentUser()
    println(user?["localidade"])
    //fim obter localidade

}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError!)
{
    println("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
}

//fim local


// MARK: Parse Login

func logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController, shouldBeginLogInWithUsername username: String, password: String) -> Bool {


    if (!username.isEmpty || !password.isEmpty) {
        return true
    }else {
        return false
    }

}



func logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController, didLogInUser user: PFUser) {

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("aposLogin", sender: self)


}

func logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController, didFailToLogInWithError error: NSError?) {
    println("Failed to login...")
}

func logInViewControllerDidCancelLogIn(logInController: PFLogInViewController) {

}

// MARK: Parse Signup

func signUpViewController(signUpController: PFSignUpViewController, didSignUpUser user: PFUser) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
func signUpViewController(signUpController: PFSignUpViewController, didFailToSignUpWithError error: NSError?) {

    println("FAiled to sign up...")

}



func signUpViewControllerDidCancelSignUp(signUpController: PFSignUpViewController) {

    println("User dismissed sign up.")

}

// MARK: Actions

@IBAction func simpleAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.presentViewController(self.logInViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}



@IBAction func logoutAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    PFUser.logOut()

}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func toggleSideMenu(sender: AnyObject) {
    toggleSideMenuView()
}

// MARK: - ENSideMenu Delegate
func sideMenuWillOpen() {
    println("sideMenuWillOpen")
}

func sideMenuWillClose() {
    println("sideMenuWillClose")
}

func sideMenuShouldOpenSideMenu() -> Bool {
    println("sideMenuShouldOpenSideMenu")
    return true
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("setupCliente", sender: self)
```

There is nothing immediately wrong with this code, and you should be able to call it from where you want it.  However, I suspect that you have not set up your segue correctly in your Storyboard (I'm assuming you are using Storyboards). To do this, you need to setup a manual segue.

You have to drag a segue from the yellow button on top to the next view controller, and from there choose a manual segue (ie: manual push).  Then click on that segue and name it with your identifier - setupCliente.  Only then will the view controller recognize the segue and be able to use it to reach the next view controller.

Also make sure that each view has its correct view controller assigned to it.

Comment: Where do I place the code? I can't figure it out... `signUpViewController`? Dont work.

I have a segue via storyboard with push and StoryboardID "setupCliente", but after signup, dont go.

Comment: Okay, I'm commenting again after trying it out for myself and confirming that it works.  To simplify your situation, lets call the view controller you are coming from A, and the view controller you are going to B.  After hooking up the manual segue from A to B in storyboards, you want to call this in view controller A.  Where, you ask?  Really wherever you need it.  To test it, I would try it in a button click event first, so for example put it in a IBAction call and fire it that way.